# Is this capitalization of the word "Nice" necessary or is it a mistake?

Tags: the-chronicles-of-narnia, cs-lewis, the-horse-and-his-boy

While re-reading *The Horse and His Boy* by C. S. Lewis, I noticed that the word "nice" was capitalized in the print. I'm wondering if this was intentional, or if it was a mistake?

Here is the passage:

> But the next day passed very slowly, Lasaraleen wanted to go back on the whole arrangement and kept on Aravis that Namia was a country of perpetual snow and ice inhabited by demons and sorcerers, and she was mad to think of going there. "And with a peasant boy, too!" said Lasaraleen. **"Darling, think of it! It's not Nice."** Aravis had thought of it a good deal, but she was so tired of Lasaraleen's silliness by now that, for the first time, she began to think that traveling with Shasta was really rather more fun than fashionable life in Tashbaan. So she only replied, "You forget that I'll be nobody, just like him, when we get to Narnia. And anyway, I promised."
>
> *<sub>The Horse and His Boy</sub>*

The word is clearly capitalized in the book. Was this a mistake? Was it intentional? Have I missed a custom of the Calormene dialect?

Comment: I have no evidence for this, but it would certainly fit the way the British upper-middle class of the time would speak. The emphasis on the word, "nice," gives it almost proper noun status, elevating it to more than simply meaning pleasant or attractive, but invoking the entire set of unspoken rules one must abide by in one's actions to be considered pleasant and attractive socially.

Comment: It's capitalised in all six version I've checked. It appears the be used in precisely the same way that Stack Exchange uses it, e.g. it's nice to be **Nice**.

Comment: Hmm. My bootleg copy of the 1959 reprint has the same capitalisation.

Comment: If it is capitalized in all of those editions then I should think it quite intentional.

Comment: @DoscoJones - It wouldn't be the first time a [typo has crept into an earlier edition and been replicated throughout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imogen_(Cymbeline)).

Comment: Assuming it is deliberate, I'd suggest that this is better suited for the [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com)

Comment: What @GeoffAtkins says. Not a typo. Another way of putting it would be "And with a peasant boy, too!" said Lasaraleen. "Darling, think of it! It's not _nice_."

Comment: Lewis was weird.

Comment: When my kids were young, my (now ex) wife (a teacher) wanted to make them read the _Narnia_ books. I was against it, and said to her, 'Read _That Hideous Strength_ and tell me that Lewis is OK for our kids to read'. She did, and conceded.

Comment: This kind of usage is also common in Thomas the Tank Engine, and Winnie the Pooh. I think it's really just for emphasis. In https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242457/capitalization-in-mid-20th-century-british-english they trace this kind of usage back to "1066 and all that".

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - The counterclaim regarding that source, in that 1066AAT was published in 1930 whereas the Pooh books were published in the 20s ignores the fact that 1066AAT was collated from a regular newspaper column which _had_ been published throughout the 20s.

Comment: And I doubt Lasaraleen is comparing Narnia to a city in south France.

Comment: Because _somebody_ had to go there.

Comment: Not unless they're talking about the biscuit

Comment: I note that there is a typographical error in: "...and she was made think of going there".  "Made" should be "mad to".  Earlier in that sentence a verb seems to be missing between "on" and "Avaris".  Either Lewis wrote very oddly in that paragraph or there are typographical errors.

Comment: I haven't read _The Horse and His Boy_, but "But the _nest_ day passed very slowly..." Is _that_ a typo, or did Lasaraleen spend a day in a nest?

Comment: whoops. Copied and pasted off of an image. Trying out new Monterey features

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Neither necessary nor a mistake - it's a deliberate affectation.**

The rules of English capitalization have changed over time - in the 18th century, capitalizing all nouns was common, but this has faded over time, as discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization_in_English):

> By the era of Early Modern English, with the influence of continental printing practices after the English Restoration in 1660, printing began to favor more and more capitalization of nouns following German typography. The first lines of the U.S. Constitution of 1787 show major capitalization of most nouns:
>
> > We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide for the common defence, promote the general Welfare, and secure the Blessings of Liberty to ourselves and our Posterity, do ordain and establish this Constitution for the United States of America.[3]
>
> But by the end of the 18th century with the growth of prescriptive dictionaries and style manuals for English usage, the practice faded in Britain so that by the beginning of the 19th century common nouns were only occasionally capitalized, such as in advertisements. Yet the style lasted as late as the Civil War era in the United States, as some of Emily Dickinson's poems still capitalize many common nouns.

"Nice" of course, isn't a noun, but by treating it as a noun, Lewis is suggesting that the word is being treated as a special term, by someone who is snobbish and silly (and who therefore, might also be using old-fashioned English rules).

Lewis uses unusual capitalization in The Silver Chair as well (see "They" below):

> Owing to the curious methods of teaching at Experiment House, one did not learn much French or Maths or Latin or things of that sort; but one did learn about getting away quickly when They were looking for one.

and in *Voyage of the Dawn Treader*:

> They had got there of course by Magic, which is the only way of getting to Narnia.

Other works of the same era that used unusual capitalization for effect are the humorous "history" manual *1066 and All That* (1930), which describes the English Civil War as being between the Cavaliers who were "Wrong but Wromantic" and the Roundheads who were "Right but Repulsive."

Comment: Can you give any other examples from this work?